# why notation pat ... means zero or more expressions in scheme macro pattern

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme

When I'm reading [the macro part of The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html), it mentions that when you are trying to define a syntax extension using `define-syntax`, you should use `pat ...` to specify zero or more expression in the pattern. Why don't just use `...` for zero or more expression, in which case `pat ...` means one or more expressions?

Also, when the author gives definition of `and` as follows:

```
(define-syntax and
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_) #t]
    [(_ e) e]
    [(_ e1 e2 e3 ...)
     (if e1 (and e2 e3 ...) #f)]))
```

Why don't just write it like this:

```
(define-syntax and
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_) #t]
    [(_ e) e]
    [(_ e1 e2 ...)
     (if e1 (and e2 ...) #f)]))
```

I have tested this definition with some cases, and I didn't find any problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.19), `...` must always follow some identifier to get its "zero or more" meaning (it behaves like the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)), so `...` and `pat ...` mean different things: the former is just a literal `...` symbol as far as `syntax-rules` is concerned.

In your example, both forms seem to be the same, but that's because the pattern `(_ e1 e2 ...)` only fires when there are two or more conjuncts (arguments to `and`) anyway, since the second pattern `(_ e)` already handles the case where there's only one conjunct. It doesn't always work this way, and Dybvig apparently found it cleaner to write an explicit "two or more" clause rather than "exactly one" and "one or more" clauses.